# RewriteRule for URLS with attributes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have over 100 pages that has a ton of URLs like this:

> - product_reviews_write.php?products_id=111
> - product_reviews_write.php?products_id=119
> - product_reviews_write.php?products_id=86
> - product_reviews_write.php?products_id=87
> - product_reviews_write.php?products_id=88
> - etc...

I would like to redirect all pages that start with `/product_reviews_write.php` to the website homepage `/`.

I tried this, but the rewrite includes everything after the `?` in URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.url\.com$
RewriteRule ^product_reviews_write\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.url\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

The result is something like `www.url.com/product_reviews_write/?products_id=88`.

Any ideas? Thanks for the time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `?` at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?url\.com$
RewriteRule ^product_reviews_write\.php http://www.url.com/? [R=301,L]
```

ANd you can also combine the two conditions.